# Automate actions in Excel using Python (Click menu button, type text into InputBox..)

Tags: python, excel, vba, automation

I would like to automate the actions cited below in Excel using Python, and I couldn't find any solutions to what I'm looking for which is weird or maybe I couldn't find the right keywords to refine my search.

What I managed to find is how to open/close Workbooks, execute a macro and handle exception.

What I still need to automate is : Click on a menu button which is location in the ribbon, a form pops up then click on a radio button, after that type user and password into InputBox then click OK.

Screenshots of the actions cited below :

[Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYike.png)

[Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW9JT.png)

[Step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MChPU.png)

[Step4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdoXL.png)

A quick view of my code so far :

```py
import os
import subprocess 
import sys
import win32com.client as win32 
import win32com
import json
import time  


f=open ('*ConfidentialPath*')
data=json.load(f)
Path_VBA =data['Path_VBA']

try:
    xl = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb=xl.Workbooks.Open(Path_VBA) 
    xl.visible = True
    time.sleep(5)
    xl.Application.Run("OpenWorkbook")
    time.sleep(5)
    xl.Application.Run("CloseWorkbook")
    time.sleep(5)
    xl.Workbooks(1).Close(SaveChanges=1) 
    xl.DisplayAlerts = True 
    xl.Application.Quit() 

except Exception as ex:
        template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
        message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
        print(message)

xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
```

**Any kind of help or guidance would be much appreciated.**

Comment: Have you looked into using an Excel Python plugin like `pyxll`?

Comment: @MattDMo No I have not, actually I just did a quick research on this plugin and found out that you need a licence in order to work with this plugin on the long-term. I need a free and open-source solution for this task.

Comment: XLWings is another one to look at. It has a slightly different operating concept than PyXLL, but I'm not sure about licensing restrictions. I would image that if you're using either one for work, you'll have to pay a license fee. That's the way the software world works for the most part (excluding true FOSS, of course).

Comment: I just thought - `pyautogui` might work for your needs.

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you for your suggestions, I just viewed the pyautogui documentation and I guess it will do, will update soon on this thread if I managed to get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading `pyautogui`'s documentation and applying it to my code, I have managed to do all the actions I needed to do:

- Clicking on menu buttons.
- Inserting text into InputBox.
- Sending Hotkeys.

Here is a quick view of the code that I put together:

```
import os
import subprocess 
import sys
import win32com.client as win32 
import win32com
import json
import time  
import pyautogui
import pyautogui as pag
import pyautogui as pya
import pyautogui as py

#JSON FILE
f = open('C:\\WORKSTATION\\PYTHON-VBA\\config.json')
data = json.load(f)
Path_VBA = data['Path_VBA']

#JSON path of images of buttons i want to click on stored in a folder
BoutonGenerer = data['BoutonGenerer']
BoutonBackOffice = data['BoutonBackOffice']
BoutonGenerer2 = data['BoutonGenerer2']

#JSON path of strings needed to authenticate stored in the config file
Username = data['USERNAME']
Password = data['PASSWORD']

try:
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
    #Opening the file with os.StartFile
    os.startfile(Path_VBA)
    #Sleep function to suspend execution of the current thread
    time.sleep(8)
    #Locate function that looks for the image
    pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(BoutonGenerer)
    #Click function
    pyautogui.click(BoutonGenerer)
    time.sleep(4)
    pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(BoutonBackOffice)
    pyautogui.click(BoutonBackOffice)
    time.sleep(4)
    pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(BoutonGenerer2)
    pyautogui.click(BoutonGenerer2)
    time.sleep(4)
    #Type into fonction
    pyautogui.typewrite(Username)
    time.sleep(2)
    #Hotkey enter
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.typewrite(Password)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    
#And lastly throw an exception if errors were found
except Exception as ex:
    template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
    message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
    print(message)
```

Comment: You could share a example. This will help other people with similar question in the future

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @regisls I would be happy to do that, I will edit my answer with a copy of my code accompanied with comments for clarifications. Good idea mate.

Comment: Hi bot @Community, more details were provided in my previous answer, if anyone have more questions, I would be glad to answer them to the best of my knowledge.